# How to check if some values are true

Tags: r, any

I use Any and All functions quite a bit in R but I would like some flexibility. Is there any function that give tell me if a certain percent of the values are true or false?

```
df
    x
1   5
2   5
3   5
4   4
5   3
6   5
7   5
8   5
9   5
10  5

all(df$x==5)
[1] FALSE

any(df$x==5)
[1] TRUE
```

Desired output

pseudo code

```
60% of df == 5
TRUE
90% of df == 5
FALSE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the `mean` of logical vector and check if that value is equal to a particular percentage

```
mean(df$x== 5) >= 0.6
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Or in a pipe (`%>%`)

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   pull(x) %>%
   equals(5) %>%
   mean %>% 
   is_weakly_greater_than(0.6)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Or create a frequency table of logical `vector` and get the proportion with `prop.table`

```
prop.table(table(df$x== 5))
#   FALSE  TRUE 
#   0.2   0.8
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(x = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do,

```
(sum(x == 5) / length(x)) >= 0.6
#[1] TRUE

(sum(x == 5) / length(x)) >= 0.9
#[1] FALSE
```

**NOTE:** You need to specify `>=` and not `==` for the percentage you want to check in order to accomodate your condition of *60% of df == 5*

Answer (score 3):

Not much to add over fairly comprehensive answers but it's a fun question to contribute to.

## Data

```
set.seed(123)
dta <- data.frame(colA = sample(x = 1:10, size = 20, replace = TRUE))
```

## `Vectorize`

```
prop.table(table(Vectorize(isTRUE)(dta$colA == 5)))
# FALSE  TRUE 
# 0.85  0.15
```

More specifically to your question:

> Is there any function that tell me if a certain percent of the
>   values are true or false?

```
res_perc[["TRUE"]] == 0.15
# TRUE
```

## `rapportools::percent`

Using simple [`percent`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rapportools/versions/1.0/topics/percent) function available in [`rapportools`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rapportools/versions/1.0) package.

```
rapportools::percent(dta$colA == 5)
# [1] 15
```

## dplyr

*Results are kind of nice.*

```
library(tidyverse)
dta %>% 
    count(colA == 5) %>% 
    mutate(n_pct = n / sum(n))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# `colA == 5`     n    n_pct
# <lgl>       <int>    <dbl>
# 1 FALSE        17    0.85
# 2 TRUE          3    0.15
```